# Appengine, excel files and the 30 seconds request limit

Tags: google-app-engine

How can I upload parse and download excel files in Google appengine that require more than 30secs ? I use java poi and backend tasks, but as soon as the backend does the job I cannot notify the client. I cannot download the excel that is created from the backend task... Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach here is not to fight HTTP and a web service architecture but rather to work with it.

Introduce a notion of a job id. When your client uploads a file, immediately return a token that represents that job. Extra credit, include an estimated duration of the job. For starters, lets say its 2 minutes.

The client is then responsible for querying the server for the state of that job id using the token. The server either returns the answer, or it returns the token back with an updated ETA.

For starters, you could just always tell the client to check back in 2 minutes (or whatever constant makes most sense for your workload). As your server processing becomes smarter, you could give more accurate estimates, and decrease the busy-waiting the client does.

Comment: What if I use google drive sdk is there a way to bypass the 30secs quota?

Comment: @EfstathiosKalyvas: No. The deadline is on the HTTP request, independent of what processing it does (whether that's reading a POST body, or getting data from somewhere else). See my first sentence: don't try to "bypass" anything. That deadline encourages a much better design, and I think you'll find it's not much harder to implement.

Comment: having users hang around for ages without a response is not a good way to design applications. They may thing it's crashed and refresh etc. Instant feedback for the win.